# How can I change useState from another screen in React Native?

Tags: react-native, use-state

I have a bottomTabNavigator with two tabs. In first tab I have a useState. In second tab I have a button. What function should this button execute to change the useState in the first tab?

The first tab:

```
export default function TabOneScreen() {

  const [num, setNum] = useState(0); 
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>num={num}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

The second tab:

```
export default function TabTwoScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button onPress={"I don't know what should be there"} title="num+1" />
      
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to have a global state, Now there are lots of libraries like redux, recoil, and many more to do these. You can use React's inbuilt Context API as well.

For simplicity's sake, I am providing an example with [Jotai](https://docs.pmnd.rs/jotai/introduction)

Create a file `atom.js`

```
import { atom } from 'jotai'

export const numberAtom = atom(0)
```

Now use the atom in both Tab One and Tab Two

```
import { useAtom } from 'jotai';
import { numberAtom } from './atom';

export default function TabOneScreen() {

  const [num, setNum] = useAtom(numberAtom); 
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>num={num}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

```
import { useAtom } from 'jotai';
import { numberAtom } from './atom';

export default function TabTwoScreen() {
  const [num, setNum] = useAtom(numberAtom); 
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button onPress={()=> setNum(1)} title="num+1" />
      
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Don't forget to install `jotai`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish what you're doing is to set up a context using React.createContext to hold state that can be shared between the two screens.

For example, you could have a TabScreenContext that holds number state/setState and wraps your navigation within a TabScreenContext.Provider.

Then you can import the context in each screen to read the value and update it in your onPress function.